# Cannot find module 'RCTDeviceEventEmitter' from 'react-native-implementation.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have this simple class, with a method that just takes an event and calls `DeviceEventEmitter`, and then returns:

```
'use strict';

const {DeviceEventEmitter} = require('react-native');
class MyDispatcher {

    subscribe(eventName, handler) {
        return {
            eventName: eventName,
            subscription: DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(eventName, handler),
        };
    }

}

module.exports = new MyDispatcher();
```

I would like to see if `DeviceEventEmitter` is called so I wrote this test:

```
import {DeviceEventEmitter} from 'react-native';
import MyDispatcher from '../MyDispatcher';


describe('myDispatcher', () => {

  test('DeviceEventEmitter gets a listener', () => {

    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener = jest.fn();
    MyDispatcher.subscribe('myHandler', 'myEvent');

    expect(DeviceEventEmitter.addListener.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('myHandler');
    expect(DeviceEventEmitter.addListener.mock.calls[0][1]).toBe('myEvent');
  });

});
```

My issue is that I am getting:

```
Cannot find module 'RCTDeviceEventEmitter' from 'react-native-implementation.js'
 at Object.<anonymous> (MyDispatcher.js:3:52)
```

Any idea what could be the cause of this error?

Also, I know the code doesn't do much, I'm just using it to see how Jest works. Only after I make the test pass, I will make the component more meaningful.